# Iterate nested hash to get an array of strings

Tags: ruby

I have a nested hash like this:

```
s = Struct.new :topic_version

s_blank = s.new
s_bar = s.new "bar"
s_foo = s.new "foo"

h = {
  :aa=>{:services=>[nil, s_blank, s_bar]},
  :ab=>{:services=>[s_blank, nil, s_bar, s_bar]},
  :ac=>{:services=>[nil, s_foo, s_blank]}
}
```

And I'd like to get an array of string values eg. `["bar", baz"]`

My attempt is:

```
@topic_version_collection = []
h.each do |key, value| 
  value[:services].each do |v|
    @topic_version_collection << v.topic_version
  end
end
```

And it works if there aren't any `nil` values in the array.

But how can I make it work with nils?

Comment: Where does `"baz"` come from? Can you add an `if !v.nil?` check?

Comment: Note it is more idiomatic to capitalize classes: `S = Struct.new :topic_version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lazy way here is to use the conditional navigation operator, or in other words:

```
v&.topic_version
```

Where that returns `nil` if `v` is `nil`.

That's just scratching the surface, though. When you see the pattern:

```
x = [ ]
y.each do |z|
  x << z.a
end
```

What you really want is:

```
x = y.map(&:a)
```

Where `map` helps transform values in one array to values in another using a 1:1 *mapping*.

To build up to a solution here first strip out the `values` from the Hash, then pull the `:services` key in that nested Hash, then call `topic_version` on all non-`nil` entries. Since those can return `nil`, strip out `nil` with `compact` at the end.

In other words:

```
h.values.map do |v|
  v[:services]
end.flat_map do |v|
  v.compact.map(&:topic_version)
end.compact
```

Now if you want them unique, add `.uniq` at the end.

The `flat_map` here is a way of combining multiple result arrays into a singular final result.